# Convert string consisting of number pairs separated by ',' into tuples of type int

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a string in the following format.

```
'1 2, 3 4, 5 6, 7 8'
```

How can I convert it into a list of tuples (of type int) in the following format?

```
[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)]
```

I think it could be done using regular expressions but I'm having trouble with the expression itself.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it could be done with regular expressions. But I find it often much easier to just use string methods and list comprehensions to accomplish such things.

```
s = '1 2, 3 4, 5 6, 7 8'

[tuple(int(i) for i in x.split()) for x in s.split(',')]
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this couldn't be done with regexes, because those will just output strings. You need to split by comma, then split each element again by space:

```
[tuple(elem.split(" ")) for elem in data.split(",")]
```

Comment: this does not convert to `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `split()` and then list comprehension:

```
sample_str = '1 2, 3 4, 5 6, 7 8'
result = [
     tuple(int(v) for v in item.strip().split(' '))
     for item in sample_str.split(',')
]
```

**Edit:** Added parsing to `int`

Comment: this does not convert to `int`s

Answer (score 0):

You could add parentheses:

```
>>> original = '1 2, 3 4, 5 6, 7 8'
>>> modified = '[({})]'.format(original.replace(', ', '),(').replace(' ', ','))
>>> modified
'[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]'
```

We can then use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the string to a list of tuples of integers:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(modified)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

This is a safe way of evaluating a string (not like `eval`). From the `literal_eval` documentation:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Comment: Don't do this, this is a code injection waiting to happen

Comment: @Rob for example?

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing `literal_eval()` with the bare `eval()`. Still a needlessly complex way to do it.

Comment: I'm just offering an alternative. Our two solutions have different failure modes.